# Downloading all jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I've a number of jupyter notebooks that contain various scripts. In order to preserve the scripts I download the each notebook via the browser and commit each .ipynb file. This is a slow process. Is there a mechanism to save all notebooks within a jupyter container so that they can be added to source control or alternative mechanism for adding multiple notebooks to source control ?

I tried creating a folder on jupyter with aim that all notebooks within a folder can be downloaded but this option does not appear available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running jupyter via a docker container and all notebooks are stored in `/notebooks`

To copy `notebooks` from running docker container to current dir I issue this docker command :

```
docker cp 'CONTAINER ID':/notebooks .
```

This copies the `notebooks` folder and contents to current dir. Can commit via git or other scm the notebooks folder.